# X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars not showing up, even though I am logged in as app owner

Tags: google-app-engine

I am looking to estimate my app engine costs.  I want to look at the X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars headers, but they are not being delivered to me.  I am logged into the https://appengine.google.com/dashboard using my owner login, and logged with the same into gmail as well.

What else am I missing here?  How do I get the X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars headers?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here was that my application was using my own custom login system, based on simpleauth.  So, it was tricky to force myself to become logged into this appengine app as the google admin.  I had to create a page, and mark it as login:admin in my app.yaml, like so:

```
- url: /job/.*
  script: MyScript.app
  login: admin
```

After this, when I went to the URL under /job/, the app would bring up the google login, and I could use my admin login to become logged into the app as admin.  And then the headers were sent.